# Is the EW-SD50 connector exclusive to Shimano?

Tags: shimano, replacement, shimano-di2

I have a broken EW-SD50 cable. I need a new plug/ connector. Is this a proprietary part from Shimano, or is it an electric component that can be sourced elsewhere?

[image]

Comment: I'd start by slapping some sugru or similar product on top of the crack.  You might get years more use out of the wire.

Comment: @Criggie: Assuming it’s only a crack in the outermost part of the isolation. I’d also try to glue and reinforce with heat shrink tube first.

Comment: You can source a torn or otherwise damaged Di2 wire and splice the pristine connector  to your wire. Alternatively, you can just splice the right wire onto the left wire, making a DIY Y-split.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know it's a completely proprietary Shimano thing. When they break you buy a new complete cable of the correct length. Even if there were a hacky solution, the wires inside are tiny and would be difficult to work with.

Comment: Concerning correct cable length: the reason for the shown damage could be a cable that is either a tiny bit too short or stressed. You may get a longer one or route it differently.

Comment: @Carel It's possible, but what I've seen the most of with them is failing from the connectors laying underneath a hand position that has them get stressed repeatedly.